# How do I retireve a value from an Object converted to array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to retrieve the value converted to array and then to object..

```
$input = (object)(array) 123;
var_dump($input);
```

This outputs:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  [0]=>
  int(123)
}
```

How do I retrieve the value 123 from `$input` ?

Comment: `echo end($input);` would work but only as long as there is no other property in the object.

Comment: @Gordon, isn't that also just casting the object back to an array ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45959

Unfortunately this is a known issue about which you can do nothing.

If you are stuck with an object of this type from an external source, the best bet would be cast it back to an array to get the value:

```
$input = (object)(array) 123;
$array = (array) $input;
echo $array[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
<pre><?php
$input = (object)(array) 123;

$reflection = new ReflectionObject($input);
var_dump($reflection->hasProperty('0'));
?></pre>
```

This will show you that, while you can still see the value in `var_dump($input)`, it is not consider to be a property. And if you ask for the [`getProperties()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperties.php), you will get no output at all.

Also .. why the hell you think you need this sort of abomination? Seems like you are asking SO to patch up you bugfix of a broken solution for a mis-defined problem.